# Is it secure to enter your seed in a browser form to publish data to IOTA Tangle?

Tags: iota-network, tangle, security, seed, masked-authenticated-messaging

I am trying to publish my data on IOTA Tangle using MAM. For this, I have designed a web form where I have to enter my seed and press the publish button. The actual data is fetched from firebase database and published to Tangle. My question is that is it secure to pass the seed to back end where I am running a node.js script to publish data? Or should I do the entire publish process in the front end and pass my seed to back end?

What could be the most secure way?

Comment: Who is running the server and who is using the webapp? If you run the server for other people, it is a matter of trust if they want to see the seed being sent to the server. Signing on the client will make this trust easier (while still they need to trust that nobody added a backdoor to the website to steal seeds), and will also allow adding support for hardware wallets later.

Comment: Well, any health agency would run the server and webapp will be used by users or patients. Currently, I have added openSSL. Is it secure enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's irrelevant, you don't need a seed to publish a MAM message since you don't sign the transaction:

Example: https://github.com/iota-community/javascript-iota-workshop/blob/master/code/7.1-mam-public-send.js

If your library for some reason requires a seed just make one up, you can just publish to any address without the seed belonging to it. The seed is only needed for signing value transactions.